# Cypher: What is the system in the naming of clauses/functions?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm learning cypher and looking a simple tutorial examples such as the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()
WHERE toLower(p.name) STARTS WITH 'michael'
RETURN p.name
```

I'm having a hard time spotting the system behind the syntax and naming convention in the WHERE-clause (I'm very new to query languages so sorry if this should be obvious). I can read the WHERE clause, but I think of it as two transformations of a string - one from string to (lower case) string, and another from string to boolean. I would expect the clause to look like either of

```
WHERE LOWER p.name STARTS WITH 'michael'
```

or

```
WHERE startsWith(toLower(p.name), 'michael')
```

(or something similar). Can anybody explain the logic behind this? It seems weirdly inconsistent to me, so I'd love to understand rather than just trying to memorize what uses which syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STARTS WITH` is an operator that is supported in a `WHERE` clause whereas `toLower` is a function. Operators return a boolean but a function can return anything. Cypher is a declarative language and I think supporting `STARTS WITH` is an effort to keep Cypher as declarative as possible. But I agree technically you can choose any syntax. Overall, for a boolean condition in a `WHERE` clause, if you can easily support it using an operator, I would say it'll be more declarative compared to a function.